# Trigger showMore on infiniteHits widget (Algolia istantsearch.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, algolia

The istantsearch.js's infiniteHits widget appends a "Show more results" button who loads another results.
I need to trigger this functionality dinamically, hiding the button, because I want more results on scroll's ending.

So I try with connectors (calling `InfiniteHitsRenderingOptions.showMore()`), but I must rewrite the entire widget for only this little functionality.

So my questions:

- How I can load more results in the default infiniteHits widget?
- Why if I try with `$(".ais-infinite-hits--showmore button").trigger("click")` nothing happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The infiniteHits has very little logic in it. Here is what I'll do:

```
// custom widget
var customInfiniteHits = instantsearch.connectors.connectInfiniteHits(function(options, isFirstRendering) {
  var showMore = options.showMore;
  var hits = options.hits;
  var containerNode = otpions.widgetParams.containerNode;

  if(isFirstRendering) {
    bindScroll(showMore);
  }

  containerNode.html(
    hits.map(function(hit) {
      return '<div>' + hit._highlightResult.name.value + '</div>';
    })
  );
});

// Usage
search.addWidget(
  customInfiniteHits({
    containerNode: $('#custom-infinite-hits-container'),
  })
);
```

`bindScroll` is the function that will listen to scroll position and will call the `showMore` provided. This function does not take parameters.

Comment: That's what I've tried but I don't know how to use mustache templates with this configuration and the url sync don't work anymore...

Comment: Indeed you can't use mustache in this context. String litteral could help you here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals